# Control running of jars through ShellExecuteEx

Tags: java, c++, shell, shellexecuteex

we have a Java project. It has 5 CLI commands which point to the Project.jar

they go something like

1. example server: this is a server process which keeps running in the CMD and doesn't close.
2. example client agent: this is a client process which keeps running in second CMD and doesn't close. This cannot start until "example server" has started completely.

3, 4, 5: these are following commands like "example login,... example write" etc which can be run in a single cmd. These cannot start until "example server" and "example client" have started completely.

Now I am trying to run all these jars through a C++ executable

I could not use shell execute as, if i gave shellexecute for each of the java -jar commands, they all ran at once(which i don't want). So I use ShellExecuteEx something like this:

```
 SHELLEXECUTEINFO A= { 0 };
A.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
A.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
A.hwnd = NULL;
A.lpVerb = NULL;
A.lpFile = L"\\java.exe";
A.lpParameters = L"-jar";
A.lpDirectory = NULL;
A.nShow = SW_SHOW;
A.hInstApp = NULL;
ShellExecuteEx(&A);
WaitForSingleObject(A.hProcess, 20000);

 SHELLEXECUTEINFO B= { 0 };
B.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
B.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
B.hwnd = NULL;
B.lpVerb = NULL;
B.lpFile = L"\\java.exe";
B.lpParameters = L"-jar";
B.lpDirectory = NULL;
B.nShow = SW_SHOW;
B.hInstApp = NULL;
ShellExecuteEx(&B);
WaitForSingleObject(B.hProcess, 20000);


  SHELLEXECUTEINFO C= { 0 };
C.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
C.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
C.hwnd = NULL;
C.lpVerb = NULL;
C.lpFile = L"\\java.exe";
C.lpParameters = L"-jar";
C.lpDirectory = NULL;
C.nShow = SW_SHOW;
C.hInstApp = NULL;
ShellExecuteEx(&A);
WaitForSingleObject(C.hProcess, 10000);
```

Now i know hardcoding the time is not a good practice. Can I do something such that C will execute after A and B have started?

Comment: I do not think your problem is with hardcoded timeouts. You can hardcode them, it is OK in this scenario. The problem is that you have no way of knowing that the process is actually ready. You need some process-level signalling mechanism for that.

Comment: @SergeyA you were right.